# merge two list of dfs into list of dfs first by dfs name, than by columnname R

Tags: r, list, merge

I do have two lists of a dataframe `extract2_HW` and `extract_hw_help`.
I used to bind both list of dfs by `rbind_labelled` (rdhs library), similar to `rbind`. Afterwards I preformed an merge by:

```
Results <- merge(comb_extract_hw_help, 
                              comb_extract_HW,  by.x = c("hhid", "hvidx", "SurveyId"),
                              by.y =c("hwhhid", "hwline", "SurveyId"), all.x = TRUE)
```

However, I would prefer to contain the lists structure and want to first merge the two lists by dataframe names (SurveyId) and afterwards preform a join like:

```
Results <- merge(`extract_hw_help[[corresponding names]]`, 
                                  `extract2_HW[[corresponding names]]`,  by.x = c("hhid","hvidx"),
                                  by.y =c("hwhhid", "hwline"), all.x = TRUE)
```

Where the corresponding names are Equal to the SurveyID .The Ouput should be a list of dataframes of SurveyIDs, where the different dfs of the lists are merged.
How could I do that?
Some example dput

```
dput(extract2_hw_help[[1]][1:2,1:20])
structure(list(hhid = c("        1 17", "        1 17"), hvidx = c(1, 
2), hv001 = c(1, 1), hv002 = c(17, 17), hv005 = c(1894033, 1894033
), hv006 = c(11, 11), hv007 = c(1997, 1997), hv021 = c(1, 1), 
    hv023 = structure(c(5, 5), label = "Sample domain", format.spss = "F2.0", display_width = 5L, labels = c(`Tigray - rural` = 1, 
    `Tigray - urban` = 2, `Afar - rural` = 3, `Afar - urban` = 4, 
    `Amhara - rural` = 5, `Amhara - urban` = 6, `Oromiya - rural` = 7, 
    `Oromiya - urban` = 8, `Somali - rural` = 9, `Somali - urban` = 10, 
    `Ben-Gumz - rural` = 11, `Ben-Gumz - urban` = 12, `SNNP - rural` = 13, 
    `SNNP - urban` = 14, `Gambela - rural` = 15, `Gambela - urban` = 16, 
    `Harari - rural` = 17, `Harari - urban` = 18, `Addis Ababa - rural` = 19, 
    `Addis Ababa - urban` = 20, `Dire Dawa - rural` = 21, `Dire Dawa - urban` = 22
    ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
    hv024 = structure(c(3, 3), label = "Region", format.spss = "F2.0", display_width = 5L, labels = c(Tigray = 1, 
    Afar = 2, Amhara = 3, Oromiya = 4, Somali = 5, `Ben-Gumz` = 6, 
    SNNP = 7, Gambela = 12, Harari = 13, `Addis Abeba` = 14, 
    `Dire Dawa` = 15), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "double")), hv025 = structure(c(2, 2), label = "Type of place of residence", format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 5L, labels = c(Urban = 1, 
    Rural = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
    )), hv103 = structure(c(1, 1), label = "Slept last night", na_values = 9, format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 5L, labels = c(No = 0, 
    Yes = 1), class = c("haven_labelled_spss", "haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), hc1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_), CLUSTER = c(1, 
    1), ALT_DEM = c(2314L, 2314L), LATNUM = c(10.889096, 10.889096
    ), LONGNUM = c(37.269565, 37.269565), ADM1NAME = c("amhara", 
    "amhara"), DHSREGNA = c("amhara", "amhara"), SurveyId = c("ET2005DHS", 
    "ET2005DHS")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
> dput(extract2_HW[[1]][1:2,1:7])
structure(list(hwhhid = structure(c("        1 17", "        1 32"
), label = "case identification", format.stata = "%12s"), hwline = structure(c(4, 
7), label = "line", format.stata = "%8.0g"), hwlevel = structure(c(1, 
1), label = "data from hh or individual", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(`from household` = 1, 
`from individual questionnaire` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double")), hc70 = structure(c(-121, -212), label = "ht/a standard deviations (according to who)", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(`height out of plausible limits` = 9996, 
`age in days out of plausible limits` = 9997, `flagged cases` = 9998
), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), hc71 = structure(c(-54, 
-331), label = "wt/a standard deviations (according to who)", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(`height out of plausible limits` = 9996, 
`age in days out of plausible limits` = 9997, `flagged cases` = 9998
), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), hc72 = structure(c(0, 
-319), label = "wt/ht standard deviations (according to who)", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(`height out of plausible limits` = 9996, 
`age in days out of plausible limits` = 9997, `flagged cases` = 9998
), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), hc73 = structure(c(26, 
-312), label = "bmi standard deviations (according to who)", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(`height out of plausible limits` = 9996, 
`age in days out of plausible limits` = 9997, `flagged cases` = 9998
), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You may use `Map` i.e. `Map(function(x, y, merge(<code>), extract_hw_help, extract2_HW)`

Comment: That worked for me with little adjustments, hope that was right: `Map(function(x, y) {merge(<code>)}, extract_hw_help, extract2_HW)` . Thanks for your help

Comment: Your dput didn't show the names as well as one of the data didn't have SurveyId.  So, I didn't test it